# Differences between Infrared signals transmitting with Android 5.0 and 5.1

Tags: java, android, infrared

I am trying to develop a remote control app on Android. I have tested the app with my Samsung Galaxy S5 running on Android 5.0 and it worked as intended. However, I ran into problems while testing on Samsung Galaxy S6 edges running Android 5.1.

The pattern I am trying to send is:

```
new int[] {8700, 4320, 560, 520, 560, 500, 560, 500, 560, 520, 540, 1600, 560, 520, 540, 520, 560, 500, 560, 1600, 560, 1600, 560, 1600, 560, 1600, 560, 500, 560, 1600, 560, 1600, 560, 1600, 560, 1640, 520, 1600, 560, 1600, 560, 1600, 560, 1600, 560, 500, 560, 500, 560, 520, 560, 500, 560, 500, 560, 500, 560, 520, 540, 520, 560, 1600, 560, 1600, 560, 1600, 560, 39080, 8660, 2140, 560, 39080}
```

Here are the readings from arduino:

Actual Remote:

```
{8700, 4320, 580, 480, 560, 500, 580, 480, 560, 520, 540, 1600,...}
```

Samsung S5 (5.0):

```
{8720, 4260, 600, 460, 580, 420, 620, 460, 500, 540, 560, 1560,...}
```

Samsung S6 edge (5.1):

```
{8300, 4180, 500, 560, 460, 500, 500, 520, 500, 540, 480, 1600, ...}
```

Based on the reading, I have noticed that the duration for On pulse is shorter while the duration for the Off pulse is much longer.

So, is there any difference on how ConsumerIrManager transmit method works between Android 5.0 and 5.1? Does anyone has any idea why there is a discrepancy between the Samsung S5 and S6 transmitting patterns?